# Adwords Scripts - access keywords search terms

Tags: keyword, google-ads-api

I'm trying to access the keywords search terms report, and apply query on it by "Add/Exclude" column, cost, etc.

Couldn't find it in the docs, there is any way to get the report?

Thanks

Edit:
There is an existing option to save to search report and scheduled it, so if there is a chance to access the reports sections it would be great either.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this solution](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/search-query).

You're able to acquire the data from the search query report through an AWQL query. Example as used in the linked solution:

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
   "SELECT Query,Clicks,Cost,Ctr,ConversionRate,CostPerConversion,Conversions,CampaignId,AdGroupId " +
   " FROM SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT " +
   " WHERE " +
       " Conversions > 0" +
       " AND Impressions > " + IMPRESSIONS_THRESHOLD +
       " AND AverageCpc > " + AVERAGE_CPC_THRESHOLD +
   " DURING LAST_7_DAYS");
```

Comment: That's true, AWQL does not seem to offer that info. However, you should be able to script your way around this with the columns `KeywordTextMatchingQuery` and `Query`